# Redmine install from repos is having macro problems

Tags: repository, project-management, redmine

I installed [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) from the Ubuntu repos and have tried reinstalling it, but I am still having a problem where text is not being replaced thoughout the Redmine install. Here's a screenshot to show what I mean:

[image]

Please note that this is Redmine 1.0.0

Answer (score 2):

I think you are suffering from:
http://www.redmine.org/issues/7013

It's probably a good idea to re-report this issue at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/redmine/+filebug

Hope this helps.